# after few seconds that my android app starts, appears an exception message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, thread-safety

( i use visual studio 2015 Xamarin )

this is the message that i see after few seconds that my android app starts:

**" Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. "**

-My app should  should write continuously current date and time in a TextView.
this is the code i have written.. where is the error? how can i fix it?

```
namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "app4", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private delegate void delegato();
        private delegato del1;

        public MainActivity()
        {
            del1 = getdatehour;
        }
        private void Do()
        {
            del1();
        }
        private void getdatehour()
        {
            TextView datehour = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
            DateTime date;
            while (true)
            {
                date = DateTime.Now;
                String s = "DATA E ORA: " + date;
                datehour.Text = s;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Thread thdo = new Thread(Do);
            thdo.Start(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception says it all really. You're trying to update the UI from a thread that is not the UI thread. See this for some examples https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/